# Javascript setTimeout() function repeats previous functions

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I'm creating a simple pong game with javascript and HTML5 canvas.
When the user or computer scores a point, I want to display some text on the screen for 3 seconds saying: "Player 1/2 got the point!" before a 'reset()' function is called. Before I display the text I make the script add 1 point to the score. Whenever I call the setTimeout() function, it does wait, but during that wait time it repeats the add score function until the wait is up. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
window.onload = function() {
c = document.getElementById("gc");
ctx = c.getContext('2d');
setInterval(update, 1000/30);
c.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    p1y=e.clientY-ph/2;
});
}

function update() {
bx+=xv;
by+=yv;
if(by<2 && yv<0) {
    yv=-yv;
}
if(by>c.height-bd && yv>0) {
    yv=-yv;
}

if(by>p1y && by<p1y+ph) {
        xv=-xv;
        dy=by-(p1y+ph/2);
        yv=dy*0.3;
    } else {
        // Add score to player 2
        score2++;

        // Draw text on screen
        ctx.fillStyle='red';
        ctx.fillText("Player 2 gets the point.", 25, 25);

        // Wait 3 seconds, then reset.
        setTimeout(function() {
            reset();
        }, 3000);

        // However while it's waiting, it repeats score2++; over and over.
    }
}
if(bx>c.width-bd-pt-1) {
    if(by>p2y && by<p2y+ph) {
        xv=-xv;
        dy=by-(p2y+ph/2);
        yv=dy*0.3;
    } else {
        score++;
        ctx.fillStyle='green';
        ctx.fillText("Player 1 gets the point.", 25, 25);
        reset();
    }
}

if(p2y+ph/2>by) {
    p2y-=ais;
} else {
    p2y+=ais;
}

drawBackground();
drawPaddles();
drawBall();
drawScore();
drawMLine();
}
```

I'm really at a loss here.
Thanks!

Comment: for multiple frames this `if` statement could be true. That's why it's calling over and over. you need to block this from triggering after the `setTimeout` is called.

Comment: I don't think the code you've posted is sufficient to solve this problem? How is the function `reset` defined? Is the code you've posted inside a loop? It would also be helpful if you could isolate the problem and post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: _"// However while it's waiting, it repeats score2++; over and over."_ You are calling `setInterval` with `duration` set to `1000/30`

Comment: How do I stop `setInterval` for 3 seconds?

Comment: Set an identifier for `setInterval`, call `clearInterval(intervalID)`, at conclusion of process reset `setInterval`, again referenced by an identifier.

Comment: Yes, at conclusion of process where you do not want to call `update`

Comment: You have a dangling `}` curly brace at the end of your snippet that was not opened.  Look at this formatted version of your code https://jsfiddle.net/mb6hvz36/  Possible typo it putting code up here, or potential bug